# Isolated topic namespace for MQTT

Tags: mqtt, iot, mosquitto, broker

Considering MQTT's pub/sub behavior, topic namespace is not isolated and any user can access every other user's data on a topic.
I've seen services like flespi which claim they provide isolated name spaces but some of them use containers to isolate users...
Is it possible to modify an MQTT broker, e.g. Mosquitto, for that purpose? Or is there such open source broker?

Comment: The `mount_point` option may meet your needs (but you will need a different listener/port for each "namespace"). Alternatively this could probably be implemented as a plugin (that modifies the topic name; [example that modifies message body](https://github.com/eclipse/mosquitto/blob/master/plugins/payload-modification/mosquitto_payload_modification.c)). However what you are attempting is outside the [MQTT Spec](https://mqtt.org/mqtt-specification/) so I would not expect it to be a common feature.

Answer (score 1):

Mosquitto can set access control to topics based on authentication username. This allows the administrator to restrict access to topics and restrict which clients can subscribe, publish or receive messages on particular topics. This is documented in [Mosquitto’s documentation](https://mosquitto.org/man/mosquitto-conf-5.html).

For greater flexibility you can also use the [dynamic security plugin](https://mosquitto.org/documentation/dynamic-security/), or the [mosquitto-go-auth plugin](https://github.com/iegomez/mosquitto-go-auth) which allows you to use a variety of different data sources for authorization and ACL configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your time... but what I'm looking for is not to restrict access to topics. I want clients to be able to subscribe to same topic but only receive the messages they published.
As if users A and B have subscribed to topic C, B wont receive published messages of A on topic C and vise versa.
I don't know if it's possible to recognize which user published the message because apparently there is no token sent within publish MQTT package...

Comment: This is commonly done by embedding the username or clientid in the topic name. If you need for a subscriber to see all the messages from devices to a those topics, that device uses a wildcard topic name and  you make sure your ACL permits access to only that subscriber. I have to wonder what the point of what you’re describing is, though. Why is it important that they all use the same topic name if they’re not able to see one another’s messages?

Comment: The whole point is to let each user pick their topic of choice without any problem so they wouldn't need to have an eye on restrictions...

Comment: This is called "Tenant management". I'am currently also looking for a free solution for that  but it seems that this is only available in some cloud subscriptions.